# Does MagicalRecord support auto-migration and iCloud at the same time?

Tags: core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I am building an app using CoreData and Magical Record. So far I am setting up the stack by calling:

- (void) setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;

But I would also like to use iCloud to sync the store. But I need ti setup the stack using autoMigration since the app will be expanding and growing and new versions of he database schema will be required.

The only way I can find to use iCloud with MagicalRecord is to set up the core data stack using

- (void) setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:(NSString *)icloudBucket localStoreNamed:(NSString *)localStore;

Or one of the other iCloud container methods. So how do I set up iCloud sync with my core data store and still use auto-migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iCloud scenario needs to be revisited sometime soon. The changes/fixes to iCloud and CoreData in iOS7 made things far easier than they used to be, and the library needs to be updated to reflect that.

If you want to use MagicalRecord and iCloud for now, you can setup an auto migrating stack, and simply add an iCloud enabled persistent store.

Comment: I think I get what you mean - in that case,

Comment: Well, not really. You sure make it sound simple - I saw a question about multiple databases, and you advised using addSqliteStoreNamed via the PS coordinator. But my confusion is that you can't tell the persistent store to use iCloud, you have to do that when you create the PS, so ultimately, this would require a second PS be created with the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey, since the first PS was created via MR as auto migrating. Or am I missing something important here? Thanks!

Comment: The important part is when you add the store you pass the proper options in the options parameter. In this case, you'd pass your content name key option when calling addPersistentStore. Like I said, I know mr should support this better, but just haven't had the time to get to it.